# How to query on an object's key in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a dynamic key-value object in my MongoDB.

For eg:

```
{
    "cs": {
        "fromId": 42,
        "toId": 39,
        "com": "testing dilip",
        "ts": 1528199910109,
        "isapproved": false
    },
    "custInst": {
      "21705": [ 1, 2 ],
      "22032": [ 1 ],
      "22389": [ 1, 2, 4 ]
    },
    "id" : 6
}
```

Now I Want to query in **custInt** and want to return all the documents that exist in that collection where **custInt contains key 21705** .

**Update**

I want to know how to query on keys if I have an array and I want to perform sorf of like `$in` operation.

For eg:

I want to query and return documents which contain `custInst` [21705,22032].

How do I query this in MongoDB?

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mongodb's **$exists** operator:

```
db.example.find({"custInst.21705": {"$exists": true}})
```

[More information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work :) thanks

Comment: Sure, Ofcource :)